# Firebase having different env variables for functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know that I can set enviroment variable with :

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

but what i want to do is to change value of the variable when i deploy functions to cloud(production). 
Basicly i want different value of key for development and production.  How can i do it automatically without having to change it manualy every time.

Comment: This sounds like something you might want to do with a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Firebase are already built to work this way. If you have a staging project (e.g. `myapp-staging`) and a production project (e.g. `myapp-prod`) the Firebase CLI will apply functions config to the currently active project:

```
# Set the value differently on each project.
firebase functions:config:set --project myapp-staging some.key="STAGING_KEY"
firebase functions:config:set --project myapp-prod some.key="PROD_KEY"

# Deploy to each project, using the values as set
firebase deploy --only functions --project myapp-staging
firebase deploy --only functions --project myapp-prod
```